# Normalising controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angular-http

Am pretty new to AngularJS. 
I have written a code and its working fine.
Would like to know, is there a way to further shrink the controller.
My index.html file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
            <input type="text" ng-model="sea" ng-change="newSearch()"/>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
                    {{ x.name + ', ' + x.emailid}}
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers/maincontroller.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And maincontroller.js is

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http(
        {
            url: "http://localhost:8080/cordovaprojects/123m/www/customer.php",
            method: "GET",
            params: {'name':'powercom'}
        })
          .then(function(response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data.records;
    });

    $scope.newSearch = function() {
        $scope.newSea = $scope.sea;
        $http(
        {
            url: "http://localhost:8080/cordovaprojects/123m/www/customer.php",
            method: "GET",
            params: {'name':$scope.newSea}
        })
          .then(function(response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data.records;
    });
    };



    });
```

If you notice I have used the same `$http` function twice with a difference of `param`.

Thank you.

Comment: to keep it DRY you should probably turn the $http into service or at least a function

Comment: This question is more suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @maurycy noted in his comment, the way to keep the size of your controllers small is to keep commonly used functionality inside of a service.  Consider this service:

```
app.service('Customers',
    [ '$http', 
        function($http) {
            return {
                byName: byName
            };

            function byName(name) {
                return $http({
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/cordovaprojects/123m/www/customer.php",
                    method: "GET",
                    params: {'name': name}
                });
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

You can then use this service in a controller like this:

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'Customers',
    function($scope, Customers) {
        $scope.myData = null;

        Customers.byName('powercom')
            .then(function(response) {
                $scope.myData = response;
            });
    }
]);
```

Which is quite a bit shorter than what you have now, plus it is separated making it able to be used in any other part of your application (as well as much easier to test). If the endpoint changes, you have only a single spot to change and, since it's used everywhere else already, you're done.

**Update**

To bind on an ng-click, I'll assume you have an input bound to a local model, as well as a button for which to act as the click target, something like this:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="customerName" />
<button data-ng-click="lookupCustomer()">
    Lookup Customer
</button>
```

Then in your controller, you can define the `lookupCustomer` function this way:

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', [
    '$scope', 'Customers',
    function($scope, Customers) {
        $scope.customerName = 'powercom';
        $scope.lookupCustomer = lookupCustomer;
        $scope.myData = null;

        lookupCustomer();

        function lookupCustomer() {
            Customers.byName($scope.customerName)
                .then(function(data) {
                    // Do something with data
                });
        }
    }
]);
```

You can add checks inside of `lookupCustomer` to guard against edge cases (no need to lookup an empty customer name), but this should work for you.

Comment: @abbas Updated answer with ng-click example

Comment: This works fine on `ng-click` but by default 'powercom' has gone.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited your answer to get the default value.

Comment: NP. I see from the edit what you were getting at. I was confused at first about what you were asking.

Comment: @abbas FYI- edited your edit to make your edit more DRY

Comment: The same code I am using in ionic framework, but it is not working. In normal cordova it was working nicely. Could you suggest what is the issue?

Comment: @abbas I could, but I'd have to see more of your code. I would suggest asking a new question and include any of the applicable ionic code you have as well.

Answer (score 1):

It'll be better if you'll create the service for getting your data.

```
app.service('dataService', function($http) {
    this.get = function get(param) {
        return $http({
            url: "http://localhost:8080/cordovaprojects/123m/www/customer.php", 
            method: "GET",
            params: {'name': param}
        });
    }
});

app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
    dataService.get('powercom').then(function(response) {
        $scope.myData = response.data.records
    });

    $scope.newSearch = function() {
        $scope.newSea = $scope.sea;
        dataService.get($scope.newSea).then(function(response) {
            $scope.myData = response.data.records
        });
    };
});
```

And also is not necessary to create a functions in your $scope. You can use "this" and get access for your data in controller by controller name or alias like this:

```
<div ng-controller="customersController as ctrl"><p ng-click="ctrl.newSearch">Hello</p></div>
```